# Click event is not working on DOM created element

Tags: jquery, function, dom, click

i have created two buttons and a text field in DOM. everything is fine but when i call *click* method on any of them , no one works.
**code :**

```
        var BB= document.createElement('input');
        BB.setAttribute('type','button');
        //BB.setAttribute('id','BB');
        BB.setAttribute('value','<<Back');
        BB.style.position="relative";
        BB.style.left="2";
        BB.id="BB";    

        var FB= document.createElement('input');
        FB.setAttribute('type','button');
        FB.setAttribute('id','FB');
        FB.setAttribute('value','Next>>');
        FB.style.position="relative";
        FB.style.left="5";

        var RT= document.createElement('input');
        RT.setAttribute('type','text');
        RT.setAttribute('value','10');
        RT.style.position="relative";
        RT.style.left="10";
        RT.style.width="45";
        RT.setAttribute('id','RT');
        RT.setAttribute('placeholder','Range');

        root.appendChild(BB);
        root.appendChild(FB);
        root.appendChild(RT);
```

**function:**

```
 $('#BB').click(function(){
        alert("back ");    
    });

    $('#FB').click(function(){
        alert("forward");    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click','#BB',function(){
    alert("back ");    
});

$(document).on('click','#FB',function(){
    alert("forward");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `#BB,#FB` elements are created dynamically you need to use event delegation to register event handlers to these elements.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','#BB',function(){
        alert("back ");    
});


$(document).on('click','#FB',function(){
        alert("forward ");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('#BB').click(function(){
    alert("back ");    
});

$('#FB').click(function(){
    alert("forward");    
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#BB', function(){
    alert("back");    
});

$(document).on('click', '#FB', function(){
    alert("forward");    
});
```

jQuery sees the DOM as it is in the beginning.  Without re-initializing the event handlers or setting to something that is there for sure (like `document`), it can't assign a click to something that doesn't exist.